# Deploying cross-region EventBridge rules with CloudFormation to send events to us-east-1 destination bus

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

How to deploy **Cross-region EventBridge** rule that'll forward the events to destination bus in us-east-1, through cloud formation template.

Unable to figure how to deploy cross-region EventBridge rules routing with CloudFormation.